# Updating Silverlight Out Of Browser Application

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis-7

I have a silverlight out of browser application which will not update when changes are made to my project.

I have added the CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync() method within the App file and this works fine when running locally however as soon as I host it on my server (IIS 7) it stops updating.

I have tried amending the HTTP header expiration as per http://forums.silverlight.net/p/137425/306895.aspx and also ensured that I am passing through annonymous access to the Client bin folder however this still does not work.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured this out - I needed to sign the XAP file.

Did this and it now works

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign the **XAP (digital sign )** along with a **certificate**. If **elevated trust** is enable and you want automatic update in installed application without **re-installation**, signing the **XAP** and **certification** is necessary.